# How can a combination of model parameters have a lower standard error than each individual coefficient?

Tags: regression, model-comparison

I am investigating a potential interaction between a blood marker and a gene. I have built a cox model with two binary predictors and an interaction term for this purpose.

I want to graphically display (in a forest plot) the effect of the genotype in the two subgroups defined by the marker. The effect of the genotype in the markerlow group is the sum of the overall effect of the genotype (`genegenotype2`) and of its interaction with the genotype (`markerlow:genegenotype2`).

I'd like to obtain this combined effect and its confidence intervals.

My fitted model gave results as follows:

```
> model <- coxph(Surv(entry, exit, status) ~ marker * gene, data)
> print(summary(model)$coefficients, digits = 3)

                            coef exp(coef) se(coef)       z Pr(>|z|)
markerlow                1.53539     4.643    0.308  4.9830 6.26e-07
genegenotype2            0.00249     1.002    0.194  0.0128 9.90e-01
markerlow:genegenotype2 -0.93767     0.392    0.490 -1.9152 5.55e-02
```

So far I've used the R packages `multcomp` (`glht` function) and `car` (`linearHypothesis` function) for this. However, the results are surprising me:

```
> summary(glht(model, linfct = "genegenotype2 + markerlow:genegenotype2 = 0"))

     Simultaneous Tests for General Linear Hypotheses

Fit: coxph(formula = Surv(entry, exit, status) ~ marker * gene, data = altdat)

Linear Hypotheses:
                                             Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)  
genegenotype2 + markerlow:genegenotype2 == 0  -0.9352     0.4496   -2.08   0.0375 *
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
(Adjusted p values reported -- single-step method)
```

While the combined effect size appears to be just the sum of the individual effect sizes, the standard error is lower than one would get by combining those of the individual parameters (0.526, by taking the square root of the sum of their squares), and correspondingly the z value is more extreme and P is lower.

How can this be?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Denote $\hat b_1$, $\hat b_2$ two estimated coefficients/estimator functions. These are random variables, and *have been estimated using the same data* (same realizations of random variables). So naturally, they are not independent. Apart from extreme cases of totally non-linear dependence, this means that their co-variance will not be zero.

Define now their sum, which is another random variable, say,
$$b_s = \hat b_1+\hat b_2$$
The variance of $b_s$ is

$$\text {Var} (b_s) = \text {Var} (\hat b_1+\hat b_2) = \text {Var} (\hat b_1) + \text {Var} (\hat b_2) + 2 \text {Cov}(\hat b_1,\hat b_2)$$

If $\text {Cov}(\hat b_1,\hat b_2)$ is negative then $\text {Var} (b_s) < \text {Var} (\hat b_1)+ \text {Var} (\hat b_2)$.

I leave for you to think about the intuition behind this mathematical result.

Comment: Please excuse if this is trivial, but just to be dead sure: Is the construction of an approximate 95% confidence interval by subtracting/adding 1.96 times the standard error valid?

Comment: Also the intuition is that if the covariance is negative, then if one is high, the other tends to be low, which makes less likely the occurence of extreme values in their sum, for which both would need to be either high or low. Right?

Comment: The intuition is correct. But as for constructing confidence intervals the answer is not so simple. If your problem is such that you can accept that the coefficient estimators distribution is  normal or approximately so, then their sum will also be ~normal, and then you can obtain a 95% confidence interval in the usual way.